# Jquery photo upload accept only jpeg not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently working on jQuery photo upload. First user has to  upload only jpeg images. If he is upload any image other than jpeg format in the label message should say please upload only jpeg. Second When the image upload what ever the size it has to fit with the container. Third when the user upload the image can i able to upload this image into my database (MYSQL)

```
$("#imageUploadForm").css("background-image", "none");
$("#btn_del").css("display", "none");
```

Here is my jQuery Code

```
    $(function () {
     $("#btn_del").hide();
      $(".upload").on("change", function()
         {
        var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.jpg|.jpeg)$/;
           if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) return; // no file selected, or no FileReader support

    if (/^image/.test( files[0].type)){ // only image file
        var reader = new FileReader(); // instance of the FileReader
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]); // read the local file

        $("#btn_del").show();

         $("#btn_del").on("click", function()
         {
            $("#imageUploadForm").css("background-image", "none");
             $("#btn_del").css("display", "none");
         });

        reader.onload = function(){ // set image data as background of div
            $("#imageUploadForm").css("background-image", "url("+this.result+")");
        }
    }
 });
 });
```

Here is my Fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/75z6y27z/1/)

Comment: Certainly there is a way to do what you want, but I have to ask why you want to do that? Is this a backend requirement?  If so, why make the user jump through hoops (convert image to some arbitrary file type, resize image to some arbitrary size) when you can just write software to do that for them? You could just accept any image, convert it to jpeg and resize it if necessary.

Comment: @gilly3 thank you so much I don't want the entire image should be saved in the db only the file name and location path

Comment: What do you mean by the "location path"?  Do you mean the local path to the image file on the user's computer?  There is no way to get that (other than asking the user to manually enter it into a text box).

Comment: sorry not location path some thing like this for example, filename, date of upload, etc

Answer (score 2):

**#1** You have a `regex` expression, but you don't use it.

Replace `if (/^image/.test( files[0].type)){`

with `if (regex.test( files[0].type)){`

**#2** Then, to show your error message, you can add an `else` and put this in there:

```
$('#error').text('Please upload only jpeg');
```

Don't forget to empty it when the user selects a JPEG file:

```
$('#error').text('');
```

**#3** To make sure the image fits in your container, you can use:

```
#imageUploadForm {
    background-size: contain; /* Handy CSS3 property */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

#### Updated JS Fiddle

Or try the demo below (same code)

```js
$(function() {
  
  $("#btn_del").hide();
  $(".upload").on("change", function() {
    var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.jpg|.jpeg)$/;
    if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) return; // no file selected, or no FileReader support

    if (regex.test(files[0].type)) { // only image file
      var reader = new FileReader(); // instance of the FileReader
      reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]); // read the local file

      $("#btn_del").show();

      $("#btn_del").on("click", function() {
        $("#imageUploadForm").css("background-image", "none");
        $("#btn_del").css("display", "none");
      });

      reader.onload = function() { // set image data as background of div
        $("#imageUploadForm").css("background-image", "url(" + this.result + ")");
        $('#error').text(''); // Empty the error message
      }
    } else {
      $('#error').text('Please upload only jpeg'); // Add an error message
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#error{
    color:red;
}
.choose_file{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;    
    border:#ebebeb solid 1px;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    padding: 4px 6px 4px 8px;
    font: normal 14px Myriad Pro, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color: #7f7f7f;
    margin-top: 2px;
 background:#f2f2f2;
}
.btn_del{
    width:80px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:darkGrey !important;
    border:none;
}
 input.upload {
        right:0;
        margin:0;
        bottom:0;
        padding:0;
        opacity:0;
        height:300px;
        outline:none;
        cursor:inherit;
        position:absolute;
        font-size:10px;
 }


#imageUploadForm
{
    background-size: contain; /* Handy CSS3 property */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="choose_file" id="imageUploadForm">
  <span>Photo</span>
  <input name="Select File" class="upload" type="file" />
  <label id="error"></label>
</div>
<button id="btn_del" class="btn_del">Delete</button>
```

Comment: hi @blex first of all sorry for that and thanks for your effort. Actually what i want is user has to upload only jpeg images.  Second When the image upload what ever the size it has to fit with the container. Third when the user upload the image can i able to upload this image into my database (MYSQL)

Comment: Hi @blex I have updated my question in brief sorry of in-convinced

Comment: Hi @blex Is that possible to show the file name kindly please explain me

Comment: ok, that's much better @Mahadevan . First problem solved? (I'll add the label part in my answer). Second: For me, it fits in the container (Chrome, IE & Firefox), not for you?. Third, you won't be uploading the file itself in your database (they're not meant to do that), but instead, you'll store it somewhere on your server ([this might help](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)) and keep a record of it in your database - for example, filename, date of upload, etc.

Comment: Hi @blex  how to add the error label in the else part not for me it was not fit in my contaner

Comment: Hi @blex Iam sorry i am asking so many kindly helpme how to submit the image once upload

Comment: Once user upload the image then user should not allow to upload he has to delete the image then only he can able to uplod. THank you so much for your help kindly help me

Comment: @Mahadevan No problem, but calm down, and take your problems one at a time. About the image not fitting in the container, I added a solution. Does it work for you? Then, about the file upload. Do you have a `<form>` element around your file's `<input>`? Do you want to upload it normally (the page is refreshed), or asynchronously (the image is sent but the page stays)?

Comment: Sorry @blex no still I am facing issue the image was not fit in the container. Then for the Image upload using ajax method pal. How to restrict the user when he upload first time image before delete the image it shouldn't allow to add second image ........ :)

Comment: @Mahadevan I created a demo with an [**index.html**](http://pastebin.com/TD1Bg2u4) and an [**upload.php**](http://pastebin.com/7mWF34wT) file. It's far from perfect, but you can try it and see how it works. I don't think I can help you any more than that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88241/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-blex).